# Domain DNS: move from AWS to Heroku

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, dns

I had a static page on aws with a **custom-domain.com** and everything worked fine. Then, I wanted to use that domain for another site deployed on Heroku. I neeeded to unbound the domain from aws, intuitively I just deleted the buckets from the aws console. Now I have:

***404 Not Found*
Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist**

I contacted domain provider company. In their answer I identified, that the domain name uses aws DNSs, but not heroku. They also added that all the changes should be made in aws, unfortunately I do not have the buckets to work with.

What should I try to do next? I can buy another domain (it is not sufficient), but it will mean that I am defeated. I want to win, will you help me to conquer the "web bug"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html), the following configurations are made:

- A bucket is created with a name name matching the domain (eg `custom-domain.com`)
- Static Website Hosting is activated on the bucket, which provides a DNS name (eg `customer-domain.s3.amazonaws.com`)
- A DNS entry is made in Route 53 or another DNS service that is a `CNAME` record pointing to the DNS name of the static website

Since your configuration was working, we can assume that all the above configurations had been made. Then, when you deleted the bucket, the domain name kept pointing to S3. With no bucket to display, S3 gave you the `NoSuchBucket` error.

If your intention is to point `custom-domain.com` to a different service (eg Heroku), you will need to modify the DNS entry for that domain name:

- If your domain name is hosted by Route 53, go the the Route 53 management console, find the domain and enter a new `CNAME` or IP address
- If your domain name is hosted elsewhere (eg GoDaddy), go to their control panel and enter a new `CNAME` or IP address

**Bottom line:** You want to change the DNS entry.

Comment: Thank you John, thank you. Have a great weekend bro! :)